# How to trigger CSS keyframe animation based on scroll position?

Tags: css, animation, geometry

I want to trigger a circle fadeIn animation based on the user scroll position.
With every scroll down, the circle gets bigger.
With every scroll up, the circle gets smaller.

The animation would stop if the user is not scrolling anymore - so the user has to scroll a few times for the animation to be complete. If the scrolling stops, the circle would remain at a certain width (depending on how much he scrolled up/down).

I only have it running with basic CSS and HTML at the moment. I am missing JS the scroll function that would trigger the circle getting bigger/smaller depending on how much the user scrolls in the background.

```css
.section {
      animation: 3s fadeInAnimation reverse;
      animation-delay:0s;
      animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
        animation-iteration-count: 1;
      background: yellow;
      height: 100vh;
    }
    
    @keyframes fadeInAnimation {
        0% { 
                clip-path: circle(75%); 
        }
      100% { 
            clip-path: circle(0%); 
        }
    }
```

```html
<div class="section">
<h1>
Section Title
</h1>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut tincidunt commodo lacus vitae porttitor. Morbi lobortis diam lorem, sed faucibus leo gravida ac. Curabitur ex velit, consectetur vitae ligula in, fringilla tincidunt turpis. Curabitur sem turpis, scelerisque et pretium in, ornare at dui. Morbi pellentesque viverra rhoncus. 
</p>
</div>
```

[Fiddle Here](https://jsfiddle.net/z03ept9h/)

Comment: you would need js to add a class to trigger the animation when you hit that scroll area or add an observer for when a certain element comes into view

Comment: The tricky thing here is I would have to define some custom scrolling positions, so the event is only firing inside the div, at a fixed number of scrolls, because after this section I have severall more sections, that will have the same behaviour, and I don't know how to achieve this with JS.

Comment: you probably want to put an element where you need it to fire and then use an [intersection observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) to fire it when it comes into view

Answer (score 2):

This is a perfect scenario for using a **CSS Custom Property** and updating its value via JavaScript whenever the window is scrolled.

If we initially set the following **custom property**:

- `:root { --clip-circle: 0% }`

We can then update the value of that **custom property** at any time by:

- re-calculating `clipCircleValue`
- `document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--clip-circle', clipCircleValue);`

---

**Working Example** *(click Full Page)* **:**

```js
const updateClipCircleValue = () => {

  let documentScrollHeight = document.documentElement.scrollHeight;
  let documentScrollPosition = window.scrollY;
  let documentScrollPercentage = ((documentScrollPosition / documentScrollHeight) * 100);
  let clipCircleValue = documentScrollPercentage + '%';
  
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--clip-circle', clipCircleValue);
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', updateClipCircleValue);
```

```css
:root {
  --clip-circle: 0%;
}

body {
  min-height: 400vh;
}

.section {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0);
  clip-path: circle(var(--clip-circle));
}
```

```html
<div class="section">
<h1>
Section Title
</h1>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut tincidunt commodo lacus vitae porttitor. Morbi lobortis diam lorem, sed faucibus leo gravida ac. Curabitur ex velit, consectetur vitae ligula in, fringilla tincidunt turpis. Curabitur sem turpis, scelerisque et pretium in, ornare at dui. Morbi pellentesque viverra rhoncus. 
</p>

<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut tincidunt commodo lacus vitae porttitor. Morbi lobortis diam lorem, sed faucibus leo gravida ac. Curabitur ex velit, consectetur vitae ligula in, fringilla tincidunt turpis. Curabitur sem turpis, scelerisque et pretium in, ornare at dui. Morbi pellentesque viverra rhoncus. 
</p>

<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut tincidunt commodo lacus vitae porttitor. Morbi lobortis diam lorem, sed faucibus leo gravida ac. Curabitur ex velit, consectetur vitae ligula in, fringilla tincidunt turpis. Curabitur sem turpis, scelerisque et pretium in, ornare at dui. Morbi pellentesque viverra rhoncus. 
</p>

<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut tincidunt commodo lacus vitae porttitor. Morbi lobortis diam lorem, sed faucibus leo gravida ac. Curabitur ex velit, consectetur vitae ligula in, fringilla tincidunt turpis. Curabitur sem turpis, scelerisque et pretium in, ornare at dui. Morbi pellentesque viverra rhoncus. 
</p>

<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut tincidunt commodo lacus vitae porttitor. Morbi lobortis diam lorem, sed faucibus leo gravida ac. Curabitur ex velit, consectetur vitae ligula in, fringilla tincidunt turpis. Curabitur sem turpis, scelerisque et pretium in, ornare at dui. Morbi pellentesque viverra rhoncus. 
</p>

<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut tincidunt commodo lacus vitae porttitor. Morbi lobortis diam lorem, sed faucibus leo gravida ac. Curabitur ex velit, consectetur vitae ligula in, fringilla tincidunt turpis. Curabitur sem turpis, scelerisque et pretium in, ornare at dui. Morbi pellentesque viverra rhoncus. 
</p>

<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut tincidunt commodo lacus vitae porttitor. Morbi lobortis diam lorem, sed faucibus leo gravida ac. Curabitur ex velit, consectetur vitae ligula in, fringilla tincidunt turpis. Curabitur sem turpis, scelerisque et pretium in, ornare at dui. Morbi pellentesque viverra rhoncus. 
</p>

<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut tincidunt commodo lacus vitae porttitor. Morbi lobortis diam lorem, sed faucibus leo gravida ac. Curabitur ex velit, consectetur vitae ligula in, fringilla tincidunt turpis. Curabitur sem turpis, scelerisque et pretium in, ornare at dui. Morbi pellentesque viverra rhoncus. 
</p>

<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut tincidunt commodo lacus vitae porttitor. Morbi lobortis diam lorem, sed faucibus leo gravida ac. Curabitur ex velit, consectetur vitae ligula in, fringilla tincidunt turpis. Curabitur sem turpis, scelerisque et pretium in, ornare at dui. Morbi pellentesque viverra rhoncus. 
</p>

<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut tincidunt commodo lacus vitae porttitor. Morbi lobortis diam lorem, sed faucibus leo gravida ac. Curabitur ex velit, consectetur vitae ligula in, fringilla tincidunt turpis. Curabitur sem turpis, scelerisque et pretium in, ornare at dui. Morbi pellentesque viverra rhoncus. 
</p>

<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut tincidunt commodo lacus vitae porttitor. Morbi lobortis diam lorem, sed faucibus leo gravida ac. Curabitur ex velit, consectetur vitae ligula in, fringilla tincidunt turpis. Curabitur sem turpis, scelerisque et pretium in, ornare at dui. Morbi pellentesque viverra rhoncus. 
</p>

<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut tincidunt commodo lacus vitae porttitor. Morbi lobortis diam lorem, sed faucibus leo gravida ac. Curabitur ex velit, consectetur vitae ligula in, fringilla tincidunt turpis. Curabitur sem turpis, scelerisque et pretium in, ornare at dui. Morbi pellentesque viverra rhoncus. 
</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! This works for one section. How could I adjust the code if I have 2-3 consecutive full-height sections with the same behaviour, and I would have to re-start the animation on the next sections?

Comment: That's your homework. Good luck! Come back and ask questions if you get really stuck. (And before you ask any questions add your workings to your question above to show how far you've got.)